# Multiple Instances of the Same Component in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, react-redux

How can I have multiple instances of the same container component in React-Redux?
Even if I send unique data then also each of the component gets the data of the last component only as the Store is updated using that values.
eg -

```
<ContainerInstance1 data={data1}/>
<ContainerInstance2 data={data2}/>
```

Container Instance 1 will get the data from the store that is modified by Container Instance 2 while rendering.
How to use so that it can get the data correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some issues, possibly in your reducer - most likely data1 and data2 are in fact the same object.

Make sure you are not mutating state, but instead returning a new state object from your reducers.

If the two data objects above are truely not the same data object - there is no reason why the above shouldn't work as you think it should. In other words, there isn't an issue with the code above, but rather somewhere else.

Comment: Both are similar container components, changed the question accordingly. They are two different instances of the same container component.

Comment: My answer holds then - seems like an issue elsewhere

Comment: Can you provide a small snippet code for the Store and the reducer as well?